# set_charset utf8mb4 not working in php 5.3

Tags: php, mysqli, php-5.3

For some reason i can't change the charset of the mysqli connection to `utf8mb4` on PHP 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, etc... up to PHP 5.4.0.

I have a class which extends mysqli and in the constructor after i successfully connect to the database, i have this code to change the connection charset

```
parent::set_charset('utf8mb4')
```

On every PHP version from 5.4.0 and above it returns true and the charset is changed, but on PHP 5.3 it always returns false and the charset remains `latin1`. Has anyone encountered this problem? any idea how to fix it?

PHP Info.

```
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    1
Persistent cache    enabled
put_hits    0
put_misses  0
get_hits    0
get_misses  0
size    2000
free_items  2000
references  3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.cache_size   2000    2000
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
Command buffer size     2048
Read buffer size    32768
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    Yes
```

Comment: Why are you using PHP5.3 - End-of-life = 14 Aug 2014

Comment: Script testing with backwards compatibility

Comment: If I were you I would stop worrying about such an old version of PHP. Upgrade to PHP 7.4 and ignore issues with the old version. It hasn't been supported for many years

Comment: If you want to know the reason why it doesn't work it is probably because your MySQL client library version is less than 5.0.6. Since PHP 5.4 the default is mysqlnd so this limitation no longer applies.

Comment: PHP 7.2 is only getting security fixes and as of sometime in december will also be End-Of-Life.

Comment: Check in phpinfo what is the version of "Client API library version"

Comment: @Dharman you right and i will upgrade to php 7, however i still want to know why the damn thing doesn't work.

Comment: @Dharman I have MsSQL 5.7 on all php installations

Comment: I don't mean your MySQL server version. I meant libmysql version

Comment: @Dharman you are wright here is the problem mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $

Comment: If you are using mysqlnd then you should not have any problems with it. mysqlnd has a shim in place that calls `SET NAMES` instead. How do you know this function doesn't work? Can you post in the question the part of phpinfo with mysqli information?

Comment: @Dharman I've posted all the info on mysql from the php info